# Where are my Siebel Business Services?

Tags: service, client, siebel

in Siebel I can create Business Services at 2 locations:

1. Siebel Client
2. Siebel Tools

In the Siebel Client I cannot see the Business Services created in Siebel Tools, and vice versa. 
(After creating a new Business Service in Siebel Tools, I compiled it - no errors reported - and ran the client with "Debug" from the Siebel Tools menu.)

Do you know, why?

Thanks!

Edit: I use the Sample data base, I did not check in or check out anything. I am not comfortable with the deployment process yet and just digging through the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrote the business service using server script, then the business service will be compiled into the SRF.  There will be no physical files outside of the SRF itself, and it will not show up in the Siebel client.

If you wrote the business service using browser script, then the business service will be converted to an external .js file and dropped in whatever your script directory.  The script directory is specified in Tools or in the genbscript command-line utility.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I was also confused about repositories and separate Tools/Client .srf files. Maybe the following about repositories and .srf files could help other Siebel newbs like me:
(http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1036342)

Answer (score 1):

Perfect explanation of the difference between repository business services and run-time business services is provided [here](http://siebelunleashed.com/client-side-vs-tools-side-business-service/):

Just copy-paste it:

> In Siebel we can write business services in two places.
>
> - Siebel Client
> - Siebel Tools
>
> There is nothing different in the scripting that we do but there are
>   differences in how these business services are executed.
>
> As far my knowledge (which is pretty limited :) ) is concerned the
>   difference between them are as following.
>
> Client side is SRF independent and Tools is SRF dependent (Which
>   means an SRF change is required even if we want to make a slight
>   change)
>       Siebel Client BS Compiled at Runtime and Siebel Tools BS is compiled when we compile the SRF
>
> When you have to make decision of writing a Business Service following
>   factors can affect your decision.
>
> Performance: Tools BS has slight advantage of Performance
>   (Theoretically) as it is compiled before hand and just executed at run
>   time.
>
> Flexibility: Client BS offers you ultimate flexibility as you can
>   change the code anytime you want to. So, if flexibility is more
>   important to you then Client BS is for you.
>
> IDE: From developers perspective Tools BS provides you better IDE and
>   better syntax checking. Client Side BS has a crappy IDE and zilch
>   syntax checking,just a field where we write the code.(I have spent
>   hours debugging Client Side BS just to find out that I had misspelled
>   a variable name :( )
>
> But still I have not come across even a single solid point that can
>   help us to determine exactly when we should use Client Side BS or
>   Tools Side BS. It mostly depends on developer’s choice who is writing
>   the BS. So, I am leaving this post as an open question asking you all
>   about your inputs which can help us to take right decision as right
>   time.